# What is the order of execution of the scripts at /etc/rc0...6.d/?

Tags: scripts, runlevel

The scripts linked at /etc/rc0...6.d/ have numbers at the begining right after the letter S/K, so the question is what is order of execution? From the lower to higher or higher to lower? I also would like to know if there is any rules on these number, can I create a script with number 1, 2, ..., 97, 98, or only some specific numbers are allowed?

I'd like to run a script after the system boot and before the system shutdown, but as those scripts needs internet connection to perform its tasks at which runlevel folder should I place it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're run low to high. Here's [a good TLDP page on runlevels in general](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/run-levels-intro.html).

You can use whatever number you like. They're sorted  by number to give some systems prioroty over others. These are loaded sequentially. It's not event-driven like Upstart.